# Is there something like Redux for Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to update some states of a parent child, I need to rebuild a widget that is 3 levels up of a widget that is updating an state.
I was wondering if there is something like Redux in Flutter to connect the entire application and to share the state between widgets.

Comment: check https://pub.dartlang.org

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely!

There's a [`redux` package on Pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redux) for that.
To get started implementing a reactive state management in Flutter, I especially recommend taking a look at [Brian Egan's architecture examples](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples) or the ["Pragmatic State Management with Flutter"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I) session from Google I/O.

Comment: That link is dead but here is an [updated one with the flutter samples](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples)

Comment: @Nolence Oh, thank you. I updated the link for future visitors